# is there a datatemplate for grid panel elements in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, datatemplate

Fairly new to WPF...

I have a collection of data I would like to bind to a grid panel.  Each object contains its grid row and column, as well as stuff to fill in at the grid location.  I really like how I can create data templates in the listbox XAML to create a UI with almost nothing in the code behind for it.  Is there a way to create a data template for grid panel elements, and bind the panel to a data collection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use an `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` as its panel. Here is an example. XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="myItems">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding MyRow}" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding MyColumn}" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Codebehind (for testing purposes):

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myItems.ItemsSource = new[] {
            new {MyRow = 0, MyColumn = 0, MyText="top left"},
            new {MyRow = 1, MyColumn = 1, MyText="middle"},
            new {MyRow = 2, MyColumn = 2, MyText="bottom right"}
        };
    }
```

Comment: This works nicely if you have a known number of rows to display, but it doesn't let you display an arbitrary number of rows based on how many you have data for.

Comment: I was trying to set the row and column from the DataTemplate (on the root element in the template) and was wondering why it wasn't working. This helped tremendously. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, but why don't you try setting the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl (ListBox, ListView) to a UniformGrid. Something like this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

It's similar to the previous solution, only a little more dynamic.