# Applying DataTemplate to a Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

How is a `DataTemplate` applied to a `Grid`?

I have a `DataTemplate` named *DataGrid_Template* in my `Resources.xaml` file that I would like to apply to a `Grid` in *View.xaml*.

**Resources.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary ... >
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataGrid_Template">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions ... />
            <DockPanel ... />
            <DataGrid ... />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**View.xaml**

```
<UserControl ... >
    <Grid /> <!-- want to apply DataGrid_Template to this -->
</UserControl>
```

I tried using the `Grid` *property* `TemplatedParent`, but that seems to be a read-only *property*.

Comment: Are you trying to use the Grid as an `ItemsControl`, or as something more complex?

Comment: see those links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251081/is-there-a-datatemplate-for-grid-panel-elements-in-wpf , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223174/changing-wpf-stackpanel-template -> you can't do it directly

Comment: @Tyrsius I'm not using the `Grid` as an `ItemsControl`. See the updated code-snippet for `Resources.xaml`. I'm trying to have a `DockPanel` and a `DataGrid`.

Comment: @Clueless @Tyrsius Sorry, I think I got everyone confused with a typo in my code-snippet. I meant `DataTemplate`, but incorrectly typed in `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot apply `DataTemplates` to panels (e.g. Grid).

If you just want that template placed somwhere then you can use a `ContentControl` and set it as the `ContentTemplate` via `StaticResource`.

(`ContentControl.Content` needs to be set to something, otherwise the `ContentTemplate` is not applied, if there is no real "content" setting the `Template` instead should work as well.)

Comment: That worked perfectly well! Sorry I think I confused everyone with a typo in my code-snipped. I meant `DataTemplate`, but incorrectly typed in `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: @user640378: A control template would probably work as well (as you do not appear to have any data that is used in the `Content`), you'd just assign it as the `ContentControl.Template`.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, here's an example of the XAML to use the DataTemplate, where GridSettingsTemplate is the name of your DataTemplate containing the defition for the grid. Set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Stretch or your grid will look different than before you migrated it into the DataTemplate:     <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GridSettingsTemplate}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />

Comment: To add to this answer, I also had to set Content={Binding} on the ContentControl to get this to work (got the idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15389304/2868438)