# Using DataTrigger to apply different Views to the same ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, datatrigger

I have a ViewModel where I created a `bool DisplaySummary` property. When this is true, a `SummaryView` is to be use to render that ViewModel, otherwise a `DatailedView` is to be used.

I am in doubt about how I should proceed from here:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AwesomeViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style>
                 #### WHAT I SHOULD PUT HERE?
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SummaryTemplate">
    <vw:SummaryViewScreen />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailedTemplate">
    <vw:DetailedViewScreen />
</DataTemplate>
```

EDIT: at first I tried to use `DataTemplateSelector`, but since it does not respond to PropertyChanged, I had to use DataTriggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DataTrigger` to switch `ContentTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AwesomeViewModel}">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                Value="{StaticResource DetailedTemplate}"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplaySummary}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{StaticResource SummaryTemplate}"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </ContentControl.Style>
   </ContentControl>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Aha! I think `ContentTemplate` was the missing link. Gonna try it right now and give some feedback as soon as possible!

Comment: Well I am having a problem here with Bindings. Apparently is not enough to use `<ContentControl Content={Binding}>`. Some relevant information is given here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18868668/401828) and here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15389304/401828) in the respective phrases " When you perform a binding inside a CellTemplate you're actually binding to the cell's DataContext rather than your view's DataContext (i.e the viewmodel)." and "Setting only the ContentTemplate property is not enough. The ContentControl does not implicitly use its DataContext as Content."

Comment: With your code I am getting "unable to cast Ms.Internal.NamedObject to System.Windows.DataTemplate", and this keeps happening if I remove ContentControl.Style at all, just keeping the `Content="{Binding}"` part (well then it gets an infinity recursion)... :(

Comment: `unable to cast Ms.Internal.NamedObject to System.Windows.DataTemplate` - Make sure you spell resource name exact as it is in declaration of resource because resource look up case sensitive. Also make sure resources `DetailedTemplate` and `SummaryTemplate` are defined prior in XAML before DataTemplate of `vm:AwesomeViewModel`.

Comment: Wow, then it works! It was your second tip: I was referring to a StaticResource BEFORE declaring it in XAML. Just inverting the order in source file did the trick. It is amazing how easily you can pull out a lot of hairs with WPF/XAML...